# Vaadin 7. How to store credentials on client side

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I need to save login/password for my authenticated user. It seems that LoginForm component is deprecated. How else can i make the client's browser to save entered login & password? Can the SubmintButton class help me somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by _make the client's browser to save entered login & password_: in a DB from the backend, or in your browser for some ulterior processing?!

Comment: Excuses for unclean terminology. Refer to this as to browser auto-filling of login/password edit fields when user tries to authenticate himself in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use cookies and implement a remember me function.
That means more or less, you create a cookie with a unique identifier of the user (never! store the user credentials in the cookie). This unique identifier is also stored in your application and should usually have lease time, which expires after a certain time, for security reasons. Every time the user enters your application, the system checks if the cookie still exists and is valid, if so go directly to the application, if not go to the login form.

Perhaps the following link gives you an idea:
http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/

Comment: Thank you for advice. i have to think about your solution a bit. BTW, did u ever use the "RequestHandler" to resolve such issue? Here [https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1977417] there is a topic where guys discuss what to do when LoginForm is inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to use cookies. I use for this purpose Spring Security with [remember me](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/remember-me.html) functionality.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/remember-me.html

Answer (score 1):

The LoginForm in the core indeed is currently deprecated as it is incompatible with most modern browsers. There is [a patch in review](https://dev.vaadin.com/review/#/c/5224/) to fix this issue, but in the mean time you can use an excellent add-on from the Directory called [LoginForm](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/loginform).